# Unable to start jenkins on windows 7

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have used the following command

```
Java –jar Jenkins.war
```

Error occurred:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Error: Could not find or load main class ?jar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have copy-pased the command from the internet, cause the `–` character before jar isn't an actual dash, it is a special unicode character that looks similar to an dash, but isn't (thank you Microsoft). To be more specific it is the character en-dash (U+2013).

So if you replace the incorrect dash with the correct one `-`, the command will work:

```
Java -jar Jenkins.war
```

Note that you might need to type this yourself since some browsers (looking at you IE) may auto convert to incorrect characters!

Comment: Thank you it worked for me now. Yeah I used the following  [Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_installation.htm)

Comment: suggest me any link to add nunit plugin for Jenkins. Currently it is removed from available plugin list of Jenkins. @Jon

Comment: @Madhuri how about this one, https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NUnit+Plugin?

Comment: I couldn't find any nunit plugin for download in the suggested link. @Jon

Comment: Yea there ia, either you download the .hpi file by clicking on 0.21 next to latest and then upload in the Jenkins ui, or you download it directly in the jenkins ui, update center -> available plugins

Comment: Thank you I am able to add plug in now. I couldn't notice hyperlink at 0.21. @Jon